# Evernote API PHP example not working on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: php, ssl

When trying out the EDAMTest.php file located in sample/client I get the following error:

```
$ php EDAMTest.php 
Uncaught TTransportException:
exception 'TTransportException' with message 'THttpClient: Could not connect to sandbox.evernote.com:443/edam/user' in /home/mike/evernote/lib/transport/THttpClient.php:196
Stack trace:
#0 /home/mike/evernote/lib/packages/UserStore/UserStore.php(57): THttpClient->flush()
#1 /home/mike/evernote/lib/packages/UserStore/UserStore.php(37): EDAM\UserStore\UserStoreClient->send_checkVersion('Evernote EDAMTe...', 1, 22)
#2 /home/mike/evernote/sample/client/EDAMTest.php(78): EDAM\UserStore\UserStoreClient->checkVersion('Evernote EDAMTe...', 1, 22)
```

Trying to run it from the browser (through apache) also fails.

When googling it appears to be a openssl issue, openssl is installed:

```
$ openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.1c 10 May 2012
```

And it is also enabled as a apache mod:

```
$ ls -la /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/
(...)
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   36 Sep 11 19:57 ssl.conf -> /etc/apache2/mods-available/ssl.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   36 Sep 11 19:57 ssl.load -> /etc/apache2/mods-available/ssl.load
(...)
```

What could I have done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly the SSL problem of evernote and ubuntu (openSSL changing something to the right thing broke evernote), which is resolved since some time: http://discussion.evernote.com/topic/26978-ssl-handshake-problems/